# How to improve FPS and overcome memory bandwidth by random access on textures?

Tags: opengl-es, textures, shader, compute-shader

In my virtual reality program I am heavily bound by memory bandwidth:

```c
#version 320 es
precision lowp float;

const int n_pool = 30;

layout(local_size_x = 8, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;
layout(rgba8, binding = 0) writeonly uniform lowp image2D image;
layout(rgba8, binding = 1) readonly uniform lowp image2DArray pool;

uniform mat3 RT[n_pool]; // <- this is a rotation-translation matrix

void main() {
    uint u = gl_GlobalInvocationID.y;
    uint v = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    vec4 Ir = imageLoad(pool, ivec3(u,v,29));
    float cost = 1.0/0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        float C = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n_pool; i++) {
                vec3 w = RT[i]*vec3(u,v,j);
                C += length(imageLoad(pool, ivec3(w[0],w[1],i)) - Ir);
            }
        }
        cost = C < cost ? C : cost;
    }
    imageStore(image, ivec2(u,v), vec4(cost, cost, cost, 1.0));
}
```

You can see that I have a lot of random accesses on a `TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` (width = 320, height = 240, layers = 30). However, the access is *not so* random, because it will be in the proximity of **u,v**.

Here are my thoughts:

- another texture format instead rgba-floats (rgba-unsigned byte maybe?).
- the shared memory is too small to even store one gray scale image.
- changing loop order. Strangely, this ordering is faster although the other should to have a better caching behaviour.
- resizing work groups to fit the textures better.
- using compressed images (Unlikely scenario giving performance boost). In theory however, that should help with the bandwidth.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: You are actually doing 30 * 16 texture lookups. I am wondering what is the purpose of such heavy texture reads on a OpenGLES device. Unless you give more info on the purpose of the code, optimisation is bit tricky.

Comment: You can brute-force optimize a depth map (here 16 discrete depth values) of the scene. By doing some matrix transformation from one frame to another, you can match pixels from subsequent frames (assumed your depth value is correct). See the edited version.

Comment: The word "brute force" and "optimize" rarely belong in the same sentence.
What's your texture format RGBA F32?

Comment: ... also, what GPU are you running on?

Comment: call it exhaustive-search or brute-force search... same thing, different name

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any actual data which shows that the issue you have is texture 
bandwidth, or is that just an assumption?

I can see a number of issues which mean that may well not actually be your problem. For example:

```
vec3 w = RT[i]*vec3(u,v,j);
```

... you have a mat3 array load in inside your inner loop, so on most architectures I know you probably are uniform fetch bound, not texture bound. This should cache well in the GPU data cache, but is probably still being refetched per loop iteration, which smells a lot more expensive than a single `imageLoad()` unless you texture format is exceptionally wide ...

If you are using fp16 or fp32 RGBA texture inputs, then narrower 8-bit unorm formats are always going to be faster (fp32 is particularly expensive).

For the following:

```
cost = C < cost ? C : cost;
```

... it's probably more reliable in terms of code generation to use the `min()` built in function.

Comment: On most CPUs (and I think in GPUs) ```A = B < C ? E  : F``` is a single instruction and hence very fast. For the rest I think you were right, have a look on my third update. By pre-calculating some matrices before the loop I could observe an insane performance boost.

Comment: Yes, most compilers would convert that into a single instruction, but ESSL has a built-in function library which is pretty much guaranteed to be fast (and makes code more readable), so why not use it ...

Comment: I did. (just for the sake of readability though). It seems like optimization for GPU in OpenGL it is a lot of try-and-error... proven patterns are not always applicable

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1**

- moving from conventional pixel pipeline to compute shader brought 3x speedup

**UPDATE 2**

- using compressed formats increases 5% FPS

**UPDATE 3**

- In this simplified version I didn't show that I indeed created many temporary vectors on-the-fly (both, in the outer and the inner loop). By removing `mat3/vec4/vec3` creation within loop brought 2x speedup. Very, surprising to me that creating vectors in loops is that expensive.

Now I am well deep in real-time and fulfilled my goal...

Comment: Creating vectors is expensive in the context of that loop because the loop is so short. Texture access is likely single cycle, so even one extra cycle of overhead (e.g. moving `i` into the right vector register location) may well double the code path length